# C print struct data shows unknown output

Tags: arrays, c, string, struct, file-io

I use a struct with array variables to contain my data set, which is read from a .dat file. After I import the data and store it in a struct array, I try to print the data set out on the main function. It shows something unknown word on the other element of the array set. However, I need the rest of the empty array element to store something else. So, how can I remove the unknown word from the rest of the array element and become empty? Did I do something wrong with the code? Here is the code. Any suggestions on that? I appreciate any help that can provide.

```
    struct Meeting{
        char team[40];
        char date[40];
        char time[40];
        char duration[40];
        
    };

    void batch_input(struct Meeting marr[100]);
   
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
 
     struct Meeting marr[100];
    
     batch_input(marr);
 
    
    for(int i =0; i<10; i++){
            printf("showmain: %s %s  %s  
            %s\n",marr[i].team,marr[i].date,marr[i].time,marr[i].duration);
        }


}

void batch_input(struct Meeting marr[100]){//define a team array of 100 records

 #define LSIZE 130 
 #define RSIZE 10

  char line[RSIZE][LSIZE];
    char fname[20];
    FILE *fptr = NULL; 
    int i = 0;
    int tot = 0;//count the number of line
    int crow =0; //count for which row is empty 
    int count=0;
    


 for(int row=0; row<100; row++){ // find the marr row until the row is empty

     if(strlen(marr[row].team) !=0){
       crow++;
     }else{
  
         break;  
  
    }
 }
 count =crow;

 
    printf("Input the filename to be opened : ");
    scanf("%s",fname);  

    fptr = fopen(fname, "r");
    while(fgets(line[i], LSIZE, fptr)) 
    {
        line[i][strlen(line[i]) - 1] = '\0'; 
        i++;
    }
      fclose(fptr);

    tot = i;
  
    for(i = 0; i < tot; ++i)
    {
      sscanf( line[i], "%s %s %s %s" 
      ,marr[count].team,marr[count].date,marr[count].time,marr[count].duration); 
        count++;


    }

   printf("\nMeeting request has been imported!\n\n");
   

}
```

This is the content of the test.dat file.

```
Team_A 2022-04-25 09:00 2
Team_B 2022-04-26 10:00 1
Team_C 2022-04-26 14:00 3
Team_A 2022-04-26 09:00 4
Team_D 2022-04-27 09:00 3
Team_E 2022-04-27 11:00 2
```

When I execute the code it shows:

> Input the filename to be opened : test.dat

```
Meeting request has been imported!

showmain: Team_A 2022-04-25  09:00  2
showmain: Team_B 2022-04-26  10:00  1
showmain: Team_C 2022-04-26  14:00  3
showmain: Team_A 2022-04-26  09:00  4
showmain: Team_D 2022-04-27  09:00  3
showmain: Team_E 2022-04-27  11:00  2
     C؄in2b: 
showmain: � qv  0yj��  _product_info_filter.dylib
showmain:  yj�� ����  H{j��  
showmain:
```

what I expect to start from marr[6] is empty output,like this

```
showmain: Team_A 2022-04-25  09:00  2
showmain: Team_B 2022-04-26  10:00  1
showmain: Team_C 2022-04-26  14:00  3
showmain: Team_A 2022-04-26  09:00  4
showmain: Team_D 2022-04-27  09:00  3
showmain: Team_E 2022-04-27  11:00  2
showmain:
showmain: 
showmain: 
showmain:
```

Comment: In `batch_input` you do `strlen(marr[row].team)` before any element of `marr` is even initialized. That means the contents of `marr[row].team` will be *indeterminate* and could lead to `strlen` going out of bounds and give you *undefined behavior*.

Comment: You also should check what `sscanf` [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: Note: `line[i][strlen(line[i]) - 1] = '\0';` is UB when `line[0] == 0`.  It is _possible_ to read a _null character_.

Answer (score 1):

The function `batch_input` (which you forgot to declare) you read six entries from the file.

But in the `main` function you print *ten*. The last four will be *uninitialized* and very likely give you *undefined behavior*.

The `batch_input` function should return the number of items actually read from the file:

```
unsigned batch_input(struct Meeting *marr){
    unsigned tot = 0;
    ...
    return tot;
}
```

Then you can use the returned value in your output loop to only print the structures that were actually read from the file.

---

As any decent beginners book, tutorial or class should have taught you, all local variables (defined inside functions) start out *uninitialized*. The values will be *indeterminate* (and you should look at it as garbage), and depending on type and how you use these values it could lead to *undefined behavior*.

If you want initialized local variable, then you need to explicitly initialize those variables.

In your case for example like:

```
struct Meeting marr[100] = { 0 };  // All members of all structures will be "zero"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, the main function should be batch_input(marr)